# Angular app crashes when custom component opens mat-dialog

Tags: javascript, angular

I've create a `DataTable` component based on *Angular Material Table* to group features like *sorting*, *filtering*, *pagination* ... The component has 2 inputs: the array of data & a configuration.

###### minimal source

```
@Component({
  selector: 'data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  private _config = defaultConfig;
  private _source: any[] = [];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  displayedColumnsMenu: DropdownMenuItem[]=[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  filters:LocalDataTableFilter[] = [];
  filtersOpen:boolean = false;
    
  @Input() set source(value:any[]) {
    this._source = value.map((item) => { return {...item, DATA_TABLE_ACTION_MENU: this._config.actions.actions(item)} });
    this.selection.clear();
    this.dataSource.data = this._source;
  }
  get source():any[] {
    return this._source;
  }

  @Input() set config(value:DataTableConfig) {
    /* ... */
  }
  get config() {
    return this._config;
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator?: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort?: MatSort;

  selection:SelectionModel<any> = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);
  selectionActions:DropdownMenuItem[] = [];
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string) => this.filterPredicate(data, filter);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.paginator) this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    if (this.sort) this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  /** Filters the table data 
   * filters are retrieved from input fields, their values are grouped as an object which is serialized as a string
   * @param jsonFilter - the filter object serialized as a string
   * @param data the item from table data to test
   * @returns boolean - Whether the filter applies
   */
  filterPredicate(data: any, jsonFilter: string):boolean {
    /* ... */
  } 

  applyFilters() {
    /*...*/
    this.selection.clear();
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(jsonFilter);
  }
```

###### html implementation

```
<data-table [source]="array" [config]="dataTableConfig"></data-table>
```

###### ts properties

```
array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    height: 1.83,
    group: "B"
  },...
];

dataTableConfig = {
  title: "List of Contestants",
  columns: [
    {
      prop: "id",
      label: "N°#",
      sortable: true,
      filter: {
        enabled: true,
        type: "number"
      }
    }, ...
  ],
  actions: (item) => [
    {
       label: "details",
       icon: "eye",
       theme: "primary",
       link: "contestants/" + item.id
    }, ...
  ],
  pagination: true, 
  selection: true
}
```

The table was efficient and works perfectly. So I created a new component to be used as a dialog (reuse the filtering, sorting... except actions).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'data-table-dialog',
  templateUrl: './data-table-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableDialogComponent extends DataTableComponent {

  selectMultiple:boolean = false;
  onSelect = (value:any[]) => { };

  private set configuration(value:DataTableDialogConfig){
    this.onSelect = value.onSelect;
    this.source = value.data;
    this.selectMultiple = value.multipleSelection === true;
    this.config = {
      title: value.title,
      columns: value.columns,
      selection: true,
      pagination: value.pagination,
      actions: (item:any) => [],
    };
    if (value.preSelected)
      for(let row of this.dataSource.data)
        if (value.preSelected(row))
          this.toggleRow(row);

  }

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DataTableDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DataTableDialogConfig){
    super();
    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmed) => {
      if (confirmed)
        this.onSelect(this.selection.selected);
    });
  }

  override ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.configuration = this.data;
  }
}
```

The dialog also worked perfectly until

#### The problem

I have a page where contestant can be (un)assigned to groups, the page uses the `data-table` component to display the assigned ones, and a button to display the `DataTableDialog` to select new ones.

Once I display the dialog, the app crashes. And I get this error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'List of Contestants'. Current value: 'Assign new Contestants'.

Which indicates that the table of the dialog is somehow binded with the table on the page.
At first I thought I used the same variable for the configuartion, yet this is not the case.

```
  showDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DataTableDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        /* this.contestants has the list of all contestants, while this.group.contestants has only the assigned ones, so I use the filter to get those unassigned */
        data: this.contestants.filter(contestant => !this.group.contestants.some((c:any) => c.id === contestant.id)),
        title:"Assign new Contestants",
        columns: [
          {
            prop: "id",
            label: "N°#",
            sortable: true,
            filter: {
              enabled: true,
              type: "number"
            }
          }, ...
        ],
      
        multipleSelection:true,
        pagination:true,
      
        onSelect: (value:any[]) => {
          console.log(value);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Any clue why?

Comment: please also add console errors.